# wp_style_add_data( 'themeslug-style', 'rtl', 'replace' ) returns "theme.min-rtl.css" instead of "theme-rtl.min.css"

Tags: gulp, wordpress-theming

I am using understrap theme as a starter theme. And gulp to compile the scss files to css for 'ltr' and 'ltr', I have in my css folder:

```
css
|____custom-editor-style-rtl.css
|____custom-editor-style-rtl.min.css
|____custom-editor-style-rtl.min.css.map
|____custom-editor-style.css
|____custom-editor-style.min.css
|____custom-editor-style.min.css.map
|____theme-rtl.css
|____theme-rtl.min.css
|____theme-rtl.min.css.map
|____theme.css
|____theme.min.css
|____theme.min.css.map
```

when i use `wp_style_add_data( 'understrap-styles', 'rtl', 'replace' );` to get the rtl css path i get the following :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="understrap-styles-rtl-css" href="http://192.168.1.12/wp/wp-content/themes/medialab/css/theme.min-rtl.css?ver=0.9.4.1619044994" media="all">
```

instead of getting `.../theme-rtl.min.css` I got `.../theme.min-rtl.css`

how can i get : `.../theme-rtl.min.css`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="understrap-styles-rtl-css" href="http://192.168.1.12/wp/wp-content/themes/medialab/css/theme-rtl.min.css?ver=0.9.4.1619044994" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it simply by replacing `'replace'` with the path to the rtl css `get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme-rtl.min.css'`

```php
wp_style_add_data( 'understrap-styles', 'rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme-rtl.min.css' );
```

Edit:
I found some problems with this approach and I found a better solution :

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'understrap-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.min.css', array(), $css_version );
wp_style_add_data( 'understrap-styles', 'rtl', 'replace' );
wp_style_add_data('understrap-styles', 'suffix', '.min');
```

the first approach was liking the `.../theme-rtl.min.css` but it keeps the `.../theme.min.css` link in the html document and that leads to some conflicts between the `!important` css, so I had to find another solution.
The new solution replace the `.../theme.min.css` with the `.../theme.min-rtl.css` then the last line of code fix the `'.min'` suffix so the link becomes `.../theme-rtl.min.css`